# How do I "merge/add" 2 confusion matrix dataframes that have the same columns and rows using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I am looking for an efficient solution to do the following using Python Pandas dataframes:

```
                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa                4                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                1               3
Iris-virginica             0                0               7
```

merge/sum with:

```
                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa                6                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                2               2
Iris-virginica             0                0               5
```

For the end result of:

```
                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa               10                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                3               5
Iris-virginica             0                0               12
```

My actual confusion matrices are much larger so I am looking for an efficient solution.

I have tried brute force going through each index of each matrix and summing them together, but that is very inelegant and I would like to learn a faster way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, we can use `concat` and `groupby` along the index using `sum` to get total of the values.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(level=0).sum()
print(df3)
                     Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa               10                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                3               5
Iris-virginica             0                0              12
```

if the indices are absolutely aligned we can just sum the entire dataframe.

```
df3 = df1 + df2
print(df3)

                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa               10                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                3               5
Iris-virginica             0                0              12
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, y not just do +:

```
df3 = df1 + df2
```

For the same given indices, I tested it like this:

```
print(df1)

                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa                6                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                2               2
Iris-virginica             0                0               5

print(df2)

                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa                4                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                1               3
Iris-virginica             0                0               7


df3 = df1 + df2

print(df3)

                 Iris-setosa  Iris-versicolor  Iris-virginica
Iris-setosa               10                0               0
Iris-versicolor            0                3               5
Iris-virginica             0                0              12
```

Comment: the only downside is if one index has different index values you will get NaN for mismatched rows